# Cleanly interrupt zeromq polling thread

Tags: java, multithreading, zeromq, jeromq

I have a multithreaded application written in Java using jeromq 0.3.2.  I'm working on putting it into the Tanuki service wrapper so that it runs as a windows service, and I'm having some trouble with cleanly stopping the threads.  The `run()` method of the proxy is a variation on the [Simple Pirate](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Basic-Reliable-Queuing-Simple-Pirate-Pattern) pattern from [the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall), and looks like this:

```
public void run()
{
    ZContext context = new ZContext();
    Socket frontend = context.createSocket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
    Socket backend = context.createSocket(ZMQ.ROUTER);
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555");
    backend.bind("inproc://workers");

    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
    {
        ZMQ.Poller poller = new ZMQ.Poller(2);
        poller.register(frontend, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
        poller.register(backend, ZMQ.Poller.POLLIN);
        poller.poll();
        if (poller.pollin(0))
        {
            processFrontend(frontend, backend, context);
        }
        if (poller.pollin(1))
        {
            processBackend(frontend, backend);
        }
    }

    // additonal code to close worker threads
}
```

How can I cleanly exit from this loop when the controlling wrapper wants to stop the application?

If there are no clients currently connected, then the loop is blocked at the call to `poller.poll()`, so if the wrapper calls `interrupt()` on the thread it is ignored.  If there are clients currently sending in messages, then a call to `interrupt()` causes the `poller.poll()` method to throw a `zmq.ZError$IOException: java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException`

I've also tried to use:

```
PollItem[] items = {
    new PollItem(frontend, Poller.POLLIN),
    new PollItem(backend, Poller.POLLIN)
};
int rc = ZMQ.poll(items, 2, -1);

if (rc == -1)
    break;

if (items[0].isReadable())
{
    processFrontend(frontend, backend, context);
}

if (items[1].isReadable())
{
    processBackend(frontend, backend);
}
```

but the call to `ZMQ.poll` exhibits the same behaviour.  Two possible alternatives are:

- set a timeout on `ZMQ.poll` and wrap the content of the `run()` method in a try/catch for the IOException.
- add a method to my Runnable that will connect to the frontend and send a special message that will be read in `processFrontend` and cause the code to break out of the loop.

The first seems a bit dirty, and the second feels a bit fragile.  Are there any other approaches I should consider?  Is there some other polling method I can use that reacts more cleanly to a thread interrupt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to extract the loop to the separate thread and open an additional inproc `PULL` socket, so that the loop polls messages from 3 sockets: `frontend`, `backend` and `control`. If the main thread receives interrupt signal, is should send `STOP` command to the proxy loop.

Exactly this pattern is implemented in my project: https://github.com/thriftzmq/thriftzmq-java/blob/master/thriftzmq/src/main/java/org/thriftzmq/ProxyLoop.java

On the main thread you may add a `shutdownHook` and send `STOP` command to the loop from within it.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //Connect to controlSocket and send STOP command
            ZMQ.Socket peer = context.socket(ZMQ.PUSH);
            peer.connect(CONTROL_ENDPOINT);
            peer.send(STOP_MESSAGE, 0);
            peer.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.error("Failed to stop service", ex);
            System.exit(1);
        }
   }
});
```

P.S. Using primitives from guava-library to manage service lifecycle makes the life a lot easier.

Comment: While I didn't end up using the approach of a shutdown hook, I did use the additional `control` socket pattern to significantly simplify the application.  The code in the link you provided was very helpful in giving me ideas for an alternative approach.